# Convert UNIX time to normal Date & Time C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, unix-timestamp

I am populating a data grid view in my program from an SQLite3 database which contains a date column using the code below

This date column is stored in Unix time and I want to display it obviously as a normal date

Is there a way I can do this as I'm reading the database into the data grid view?

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = Path.Combine(connectionPath, "sms.db");

SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

// SQL query to read the data fromt he database
SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
//Read Everything
string query = "SELECT * FROM message";

command.CommandText = query;

SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
dataAdaptor.Fill(dataset, "Messages");
// Get the table from the data set
DataTable datatable = dataset.Tables["Messages"];

dataGridSMS.DataSource = datatable;
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This is an example of a UNIX timestamp for the date/time
double timestamp = 1116641532;

// First make a System.DateTime equivalent to the UNIX Epoch.
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Add the number of seconds in UNIX timestamp to be converted.
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp).ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private void dataGridSMS_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridSMS.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "dateColumn")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Formatting
                    double timestamp = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value); // if e.Value is string you must parse
                    System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp).ToLocalTime();
                    e.Value = dateTime.ToString();
                    e.FormattingApplied = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    e.FormattingApplied = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```